# Error while multplying decimal numbers in pyhton

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, equation

I am working on a project for a job opportunity and it was asked to handle disease facts.
I was running the code and the calculations worked just fine in Python and at some point, the results started t get an error "NAN" values.

I will display the code I've made :

- The code before the error :

```
# Calculation of the weight of the population by age

#Uganda
# Sum of observations from the column "Estimates, Uganda, 2019"
total_observation = transposed_df["Estimates, Uganda, 2019"].sum()

# The weight in percentage for each observation
transposed_df["Weight Percentage Uganda"] = (transposed_df["Estimates, Uganda, 2019"] / total_observation)

##### 
#United States of America

# Sum of observations from the column "Estimates, Uganda, 2019"
total_observation1 = transposed_df["Estimates, United States of America, 2019"].sum()

# The weight in percentage for each observation
transposed_df["Weight Percentage United States of America"] = (transposed_df["Estimates, United States of America, 2019"] / total_observation1)

#print
transposed_df
```

at this point, no Nan values on the outcome. I have checked out.

- The code where the error occurs:

```
#Age-standardized rate from Uganda 

transposed_df["Age-standardized rate from Uganda"] = (COPD["Death rate, Uganda, 2019"] * transposed_df["Weight Percentage Uganda"])

#Age-standardized rate from United States of America

transposed_df["Age-standardized rate from United States of America"] = (COPD["Death rate, United States, 2019"] * transposed_df["Weight Percentage United States of America"])

#display result
transposed_df
```

It's a simple equation and the latest numbers started to break I don't know why. I also checked and at this point in the project, they became null values.
I displayed the image where the error occurred.
[CHECK THE IMAGE OF THE TABLE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFlcp.png)

Above, is the table named COPD:

| Age group (years) | Death rate, United States, 2019 | Death rate, Uganda, 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-4 | 0.04 | 0.40 |
| 5-9 | 0.02 | 0.17 |
| 10-14 | 0.02 | 0.07 |
| 15-19 | 0.02 | 0.23 |
| 20-24 | 0.06 | 0.38 |
| 25-29 | 0.11 | 0.40 |
| 30-34 | 0.29 | 0.75 |
| 35-39 | 0.56 | 1.11 |
| 40-44 | 1.42 | 2.04 |
| 45-49 | 4.00 | 5.51 |
| 50-54 | 14.13 | 13.26 |
| 55-59 | 37.22 | 33.25 |
| 60-64 | 66.48 | 69.62 |
| 65-69 | 108.66 | 120.78 |
| 70-74 | 213.10 | 229.88 |
| 75-79 | 333.06 | 341.06 |
| 80-84 | 491.10 | 529.31 |
| 85+ | 894.45 | 710.40 |

- I tried to find null values but they started to appear once I made the calculation and it's only on the latest results.
- Is not a division by zero, they are decimal values.
- Outcomes not provided, only in some rows.

Comment: Pls post your full error code and a sample of your data

Comment: Try checking for missing data:# Check for missing data in the relevant columns
missing_data_check = transposed_df.isnull().sum()
print(missing_data_check)

# Specifically for the COPD DataFrame
copd_missing_data_check = COPD.isnull().sum()
print(copd_missing_data_check)

Comment: @VultureInAtom05

I have checked the dataset and has no null values, a print from Pyhton :

COPD.isnull().sum()

Age group (years)                  0
Death rate, United States, 2019    0
Death rate, Uganda, 2019           0
dtype: int64

I really don't know what might be the reason for causing this once all the other columns work just fine.

Comment: @gtomer I added more information on the post. Hopefully you can get more details about it.